# Extra services activated when using PATCH project?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I used PATCH project to activate only doc_manager, but all services are now active.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-PATCH/

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/'$ACCOUNT_ID'/projects/'$PROJECT_ID'' -X 'PATCH' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$ACCESS_TOKEN'' -d '{"service_types": "doc_manager"}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, it seems that now there is different information about the service status in "services" and "members"?

Thanks
-Janne

[screenshot:services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RPLH.png)

[screenshot:members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXd6J.png)

Comment: my test result is a bit different than yours, only the specific service is enabled (show up in UI of members), but it does not show as Activated in the UI of services. I will check with our engineer team on the behaviors of your side and my side. Thank you for your patience